# Check if a constant is already defined

Tags: ruby, constants

This is a simple one, I hope. 
How do I check, in the following example, if a constant is already defined?

```
#this works
var = var||1
puts var
var = var||2
puts var

#this doesn't
CONST = CONST||1
puts CONST
CONST = CONST||2
puts CONST

=> 1
   1
   uninitialized constant CONST (NameError)
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
CONST = 2 unless defined? CONST
```

See [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UG) for more about awesome `defined?` operator.

<sup>*P.S. And in the future I guess you'll want `var ||= 1` instead of `var = var||1`.*</sup>

Comment: There's also `const_defined?` but it doesn't work for me; not sure why.

Comment: `const_defined?` is a method of `Module` class and it will tell you whether the constant is defined in that module and its ancestors (optionally). Check the docs for some examples — http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F

Comment: And what about this? http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F

Comment: Thanks for this answer..  great workaround for not being able to use ||= reliably with a boolean

Comment: This works great for methods as well, not just constants.

Answer (score 31):

[const_defined? API](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_defined%3F)

```
pry> User.const_defined?("PER_PAGE")
=> true
pry> User.const_defined?("PER_PAGE123")
=> false
```

Comment: This is especially helpful when you are checking if this is defined in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 4):

```
CONST ||= :default_value
```

the above works for me on ruby 1.9.3 but fails on 1.8... well 1.8 is ancient now.

Comment: :) 1.8 may be ancient, but still in use in 2017, example: Dreamhost shared hosting.

Comment: I see most projects have already dropped support for ruby 1.8. I know that there are still "supported" ruby 1.8 versions, e.g. shipped by Red Hat Enterprise Linux. They are getting security patches but one exposes to many unknown security flaws in old gem versions used in whatever application is installed.
So yes, there is, but is irrelevant for most people. Like there are and will be for a long time computers running XP (just recently spotted again such an ATM).