# What is the reason to use ||= instead of = in model to define a constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Found this in a current project:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  VALID_VIDEO_HOSTS ||= %w(www.youtube.com youtube.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com)
  ...
end
```

Usually I use simple VALID_VIDEO_HOSTS = %w(...) and haven't any guess why the previous developers used ||=

Anybody know what are the benefits?

**UPDATE**

I know what does ||= in general cases, the question is mostly about defining constant that way in the model.

Comment: I've not seen that with a constant before. Generally, the pattern for constants is `unless defined? CONSTANT_NAME`, as this answer shows http://stackoverflow.com/a/10172072/335847.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||=` is used as a cheap way to [memoize the value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), as the other posters mention.  However...

**Why memoize a constant?**

The author is most likely protecting against warnings when loading that source file multiple times.  (`warning: already initialized constant VALID_VIDEO_HOSTS`)

Answer (score 2):

`||=` memoizes the value -- **it sets the value only once** -- only if it's not previously defined.  When called subsequently, the value is already set and will not be modified. It uses Ruby's lazy loading to evaluate if the left-hand side as a boolean value, and only does the assignment if it is nil or false.

These two lines are equivalent:

```
  var ||= something

  var = something if var.nil?   # this is equivalent to ||=

  # Note: memoizing with ||= only works if the right-hand side is not a boolean function;
  #       because if it's value would be false, it could not use Ruby's lazy-loading
```

This is often used for **memoizing** (caching) if the right-hand-side is an expensive / time-consuming operation, or in general during initializations which have to be done only once.

**Why ||= when assigning to a Constant?**

Constants should only initialized once, and will at least issue a warning when you try to override them. 
**The ||= makes sure the value is assigned only once to the constant. This way you don't get a warning that the constant is already initialized.**

Comment: they are **not** identical. think about case when `var == false`

Comment: that's true. You can not memoize a boolean function with ||= :)

Comment: You can, just not with that syntax.  `if defined? val` can be used to memoize falsy values

Answer (score 1):

That call that a memoize - means you set it once, and then keep that value, like a lazy load of the value.

ActiveSupport has a method for this now that works slightly differently than `||=`:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/memoize

Answer (score 0):

It's used for lazily initializating a value. In your example there's not much call for it because the overhead of creating the string array is not that much. A better example would be:

```
class WebsiteImageHelper
    def get_image_files
      #recurse directories looking for images
      #this will only happen once per instance of 
      #WebsiteImageHelper
      @image_files ||= Dir['images/**/**']
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use it in a project to allow user to load code. User code may override that constant if user desires. So I avoid error.