# Create multilevel constant in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given that I have a constant name of `Foo::Bar::Baz`, how can I drill down through each of these levels and determine if the constant exists?

Comment: Is your question whether `Foo::Bar` and `Foo` exist? AFAIK, Ruby won't create `Foo::Bar::Baz` unless `Foo::Bar` already exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
defined?(Foo) # => nil

module Foo; end
defined?(Foo) # => "constant"
defined?(Foo::Bar) # => nil

module Foo::Bar; end
defined?(Foo::Bar) # => "constant"
defined?(Foo::Bar::Baz) # => nil

module Foo::Bar; Baz = :baz end
defined?(Foo::Bar::Baz) # => "constant"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing in case anyone else runs into this:

```
unless Object.const_defined? const_name
  const_name.split('::').inject(Object) do |obj, const|
    unless obj.const_defined? const
      # create the missing object here...
    end
    obj.const_get(const)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just `#const_defined?` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use this which eliminates the need for ActiveSupport. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the defined? operator. [Check if a constant is already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171978/check-if-a-constant-is-already-defined) has more on  this.

Comment: If it quacks like a method... ;)

Comment: To some extent, yes. But it cannot be (thanks Heaven!) redefined. Sometimes I wish that `#!` was not a method, too. Anyway, +1, correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other people talk about the `defined?` operator (yes, it's a built-in unary operator, not a method!!!), but there are other ways. I personally favor this one:

```
constants #=> a big array of constant names
constants.include? :Foo #=> false
module Foo; end
constants.include? :Foo #=> true
Foo.constants.include? :Bar #=> false
module Foo
  module Bar; end
end
Foo.constants.include? :Bar #=> true
# etc.
```

One thing I have to admit about `defined?` operator is its reliability. It is not a metho and thus can never be redefined, and thus always does what you expect of it. On the other hand, it is possible to use more roundabout (and less reliable) ways, such as:

```
begin
  Foo::Bar::Baz
  puts "Foo::Bar::Baz exists!"
rescue NameError
  puts "Foo::Bar::Baz does not exist!"
end
```