# How to check if a constant is defined by its symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
const = :FOO
FOO = :ok
defined? FOO => 'constant'
```

How to check if `FOO` is defined using `const`?

```
defined? eval( const.to_s )
```

does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a constant is already defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171978/check-if-a-constant-is-already-defined)

Comment: @vgoff: Not a duplicate to that. The linked question gives `defined? FOO`, not `Object.const_defined? :FOO` that is required here. The key phrase in the question is "by its symbol", by which it differs from the linked question.

Comment: You are converting the symbol to a string, in your question, so I am not sure how the symbol can be 'key'.  But if the key phrase is the eval, then I will agree it is a different question.

Comment: This question is obviously different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171978/check-if-a-constant-is-already-defined. The previously answered question does not assign a variable to the constant. And, I even showed how the accepted answer does not work in this case.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The accepted answer to the linked question (checking with `defined?`) will not work if you have the constant name stored in a string/symbol variable and want to know if it is defined. i.e. `v = 'MyConstant'; defined? v; # => "local-variable"` regardless of whether `MyConstant` is defined or not. Likewise `defined? v.constantize; # => "method"` regardless. Collin Graves accepted answer, with `Object.const_defined?`, is a good workaround.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `const_defined?` instead: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000487

```
Object.const_defined?(const.to_s)
```

Comment: Can also just do 
    Object.const_defined?(const)
since const is a symbol, and const_defined?() accepts either a symbol or string.

Comment: Calling `to_s` on the value supplied to `Object.const_defined?` is good practice for any generalized solution. For example:

```ruby
>>> Object.const_get(nil) # => TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
>>> Object.const_get(nil.to_s) # => NameError: wrong constant name

>>> Object.const_get(Hash) # => TypeError: no implicit conversion of Class into String
>>> Object.const_get(Hash.to_s) # => Hash
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const = :FOO
FOO = :OK

defined?(FOO) # => "constant"

instance_eval("defined?(#{const})") # => "constant"
```

This will evaluate the statement, and gets around limitations to how defined? works in that it does not evaluate anything, so we have to evaluate it before it gets the instruction to call `defined?`.

Your `eval` is simply in the wrong order.

Comment: Right, it is the same idea.  Just a difference of scope.  It is why I said that your eval was in the wrong order, it was implying that you could use `eval` like you originally posted.